# How do I find intersections for n functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, python-requests

I am learning Python  and I would like some help with this exercise.

I am doing an exercise where I am asked to plot Total Cases and Total Deaths for n countries of COVID19. I did not have any problem with that. The part where i am struggling is that I am asked to show the intersections between every country and I dont know how to do that.

The code basically does this:
1- asks the user for a number of countries to compare.
2- asks the names of each country.
3- asks for the date range.
4- plots number of cases vs Date and Number of total deaths vs Date in the same plot.

The only thing missing is the intersections of total cases between countries and the intersection of total deaths.

[Example of the output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yj3X.png)

I don't really know how to ask for a "same date" and "same number of cases" at the same time for n countries.

This is the data I am using https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/full_data.csv

Comment: what do you mean by intersections, intersections as in when the cases/numbers were the same (or where the regression equations intersect)?

Comment: Same date, same cases OR same date, same deaths. I showed it in the image. I mean, I need both.

Comment: This really depends on how the data is represented. Let's talk about a simpler case; two countries and case count only. If you have a case count for each day for a 100 days for both countries, then a simple for loop the checks `if count_countryA[i] == count_countryB[i]` should do the job, but the way the data is stored in your code is essential to be able to help you.

Comment: im going to assume that the case numbers on a given day arent going to be the exact same though so it might be better to use regression on the data and then find the intersections from the equations

Comment: could you show us the code you already have to accomplish the first parts

Comment: It has 200 lines haha, i'll send it to you via email!

Comment: Not sure whether this is still relevant to you, but what you're looking for is finding the minimum distance between the two arrays, e.g. for arrays `y1` and `y2` you are interested in `idx=np.nanargmin(np.abs(y1-y2))` to find the index where y1 and y2 come closest to each other. Then, use `date[idx]` to get the respective crossover date. Note that this (a) gives close values, not necessarily proper intersections and (b) may occur multiple times in your dataset.